# How to have one fixed link that can scroll to each section in fullPage.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

So I want a down arrow that's fixed to the bottom of the window to scroll down to each section. So I click it once and it scrolls me down to the first section, I click it again and it will take me to the next section, and so on.. How do I achieve this with fullPage.js?

```
<nav>
  <a>this is the arrow</a>
</nav>

<section id="one">
    <h1>ONE</h1>
</section>

<section id="two">
    <h1>TWO</h1>
</section>

<section id="three">
    <h1>THREE</h1>
</section>

<section id="four">
    <h1>FOUR</h1>
</section>

<section id="five">
    <h1>FIVE</h1>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using fullPage.js you'll need to make use of fullPage.js functions such as [`moveSectioDown`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#movesectiondown):

```
$('.arrow').on('click', fullpage_api.moveSectionDown);
```

Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/zyxhwbrc/